# reverse sort a 2d dict by value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of following format:

```
 d[1][2]= 0.3
 d[1][3] = 0.4
 d[2][8] = 0.2
 d[id1][id2] = value
```

I want to reverse sort this by value?

My logic is very verbose and I have a feeling that it can be done very quickly in python?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have order in Python.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered in Python, so saying you want one "sorted by value" is not meaningful. What data type do you really want? A list of keys, perhaps?

Comment: OrderedDict? http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: What would be the desired output ? It's difficult for me to understand it, since there are 2 levels of dict here.

Comment: Can you also pprovide full structure (key-values) of dictionary and as Emmanuel mentioned, expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sorted` with a comprehension:

```
sorted((value, id1, id2) for id1, d1 in d.items() for id2, value in d1.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.

Dictionaries map keys to values. They don't have a concept of order, so your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Well, there are OrderedDicts  http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict which remembers insertion order...